# Change TODO keywords of all nodes in an Orgmode subtree in Elisp

Tags: org-mode

Imagine we have a tree like this:

```
* TODO Read X book
** TODO Chapter 1
** TODO Chapter 2
```

I'd like to mark all nodes in the tree as `DONE`:

```
* DONE Read X book
** DONE Chapter 1
** DONE Chapter 2
```

What's the best way to do it in Elisp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Org has a built-in function to map over entries: `org-map-entries`

> (org-map-entries FUNC &optional MATCH SCOPE &rest SKIP)
>
> Call FUNC at each headline selected by MATCH in SCOPE.
>
> FUNC is a function or a lisp form.  The function will be called without
>   arguments, with the cursor positioned at the beginning of the headline.
>   The return values of all calls to the function will be collected and
>   returned as a list.

For example `(org-map-entries (lambda () (org-todo 'done)) nil 'tree)` when called with point at the start of a headline will mark that headline and all of its children done (whatever the done state for the current keyword is).

Comment: Thanks, Erik! It seems better than my solution. I thought `org-todo` did some additional bookkeeping, but looks like there's nothing special, so your approach wins.

Comment: It looks like you can write just `'(org-todo 'done)` instead of a lambda, btw.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this quick function to do it. Point needs to be on a heading or you'll get an error. I got help writing this from reading [this article by Xah Lee](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_find_replace_text.html).

```
(defun my/replace-todos-with-done ()
  (interactive)
  (save-match-data
    (unless (org-at-heading-p) (error "not at heading!"))
    (let ((regexp (rx bol (1+ "*") (1+ "\s") (submatch "TODO")))
          (bound (save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree) (point)))
          (case-fold-search nil))
      (while (search-forward-regexp regexp bound :no-error nil)
        (replace-match "DONE" t nil nil 1)))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer gave me some new ideas. You can check my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

At first I came up with this solution:

```
(defun my/org-walk-tree (fn &rest args)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (org-narrow-to-subtree)
      (org-save-outline-visibility 'use-markers
        (apply fn args)
        (while (outline-next-heading)
          (apply fn args))))))

(my/org-walk-tree 'org-todo 'done)
```

It works in simple cases, but I haven't tested it thoroughly.

Then I started reading [`org-todo`](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/d1bdf6c7890041d7a7234a2cd5b91e42d6b61ace/lisp/org.el#L9997-L10238) function source code (should've done it earlier) and noticed that right at the start it uses `org-loop-over-headlines-in-active-region` variable:

> Shall some commands act upon headlines in the active region?
>
> When set to t, some commands will be performed in all headlines
>   within the active region.

When it's set to `t`, `org-todo` uses `org-map-entries` to process all nodes in the subtree.

So all we need to do is:

```
(defun my/org-todo-subtree (keyword)
  (let ((org-loop-over-headlines-in-active-region t))
    (save-mark-and-excursion 
      (org-mark-subtree)
      (org-todo keyword))))

(my/org-todo-subtree "DONE")
```

I'm not sure if we need to use `save-mark-and-excursion` rather than `save-excursion`. It'd also be great to make it interactive.

With that variable name I found a similar question on Superuser: [Editing multiple TODO simultaneously — priority and/or deadine](https://superuser.com/questions/611875/editing-multiple-todo-simultaneously-priority-and-or-deadine). But I can't set my question as a duplicate of that one, as it's on the other site.